# Dynamic path in JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

Trying to access some data by key, where key itself stored in some field

```
{
    "keyName": "bbb",
    "storage": {
        "aaa": "111",
        "bbb": "222",
        "ccc": "333"
    }
}
```

In JavaScript (and most other languages) it will be `data.storage[data.keyName]`, but unfortunately I need JMESPath solution...

Trying to do something like `storage[$.keyName]`, but nothing works

Comment: You cannot access the parent node in JMESPath, so, no, this is not going to be possible.

Comment: https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.js/issues/22 there is feature request, you might find something useful here